# Antonym for gormless?

Tags: antonyms, suffixes

I was sitting at the card table this evening looking gormless (as I am wont to do) when it occurred to me to wonder, are the other players *gormful*? Is there such a word? Is there such a thing as *gorm*, that one can either have or lack?

Comment: Given its derivation from gorm/gaum, one might be able to say "gormful", but the version "have gorm" seems more acceptable (and was afaik also once regularly used).

Comment: A post like this would almost seem to be self-contradictory. Either that, or the malady ironically cured itself. :)

Comment: I'd go with feckful: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feckful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gormless?show=0&t=1293750787), "gormless" does indeed mean "lacking in gorm", which was originally the middle-English word "gaum" or "gome", meaning "understanding, or attention".  I would have to say that "gorm" as its own word has fallen out of the modern lexicon, though, and is not at all likely to be understood.  (Hopefully someone who can do searches of the Corpus of English Language Texts or the like can provide extra information....)

Comment: Nor have I ever found *gormful* in a dictionary, but people usually recognize the intent. I use it only in informal situations.

Comment: The OED knows no adjective that begins with "gorm-" and means the opposite of "gormless".

Comment: @Cerberus Why oh why is *gormandize* already taken?

Comment: If you’re going to go with a whimsical coinage, why not _gorm-packed_?  Too much?

Comment: So a gormful person would seem to be the sort of person who is engaged and attentive in a way that denotes a razor sharp understanding of the world and/or the current situation.

Answer (score 2):

Enlightened would be a good antonym for this, as the other answers suggest that Gorm means 'understanding'. Someone full of understanding is enlightened.

Comment: As per my comment on the answer above I feel the meaning would be more specific.